# Preventing exceeding a heap when reading a large text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a small program that will process large(up to infinite) text files. The processing will be rather simple(trimming and processing parts of it into separate Strings and then printing them). However since the length of the data can be infinite I might come across exceeding heap problem. The first solution that came to my mind is using a Stream to process the data. However, lines() method from Files class can divide text only into lines. And my lines can also be infinitely long!

Another solution that I came across is using scanner useDelimiter method that way:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner("file.txt");
input.useDelimiter(" "); 

while(input.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(input.next());
}
```

Would this method prevent Java from reading all the file at once and actually allow me to process file word by word without exceeding heap?

Are there some more efficient solutions (not too complex for a beginner) in Java?

Comment: *"Would this method prevent Java from reading all the file at once..."* Yes. Well, not so much *prevent* as "not ask it to" which comes to the same thing. It will read in blocks looking for delimiters, not the whole file.

Comment: Why would you want to read the entire file into memory?  (By the way, `input.useDelimiter(" ");` is unnecessary and redundant.  The default delimiter is already whitespace characters.)

Comment: Does the entire file needs to be in the memory? you could refer to this https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to simulate your heap error but couldn't. With the data I could generate, your method is also working fine.

However, if you are looking for a streams based way, this should work. `Scanner.tokens()` gives a `Stream<String>` of the tokens based on your delimiter.

```java
try( Scanner input = new Scanner( new File( "file.txt" ) ); ){
    input.useDelimiter( " " );
    input.tokens().forEach( m -> System.out.println( m ) );
}
catch( FileNotFoundException e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```